# How to format a HDD in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: partitioning, windows-7, hard-drive, filesystem, format

So i recently switched to Ubuntu from Opensuse, and i'm loving it. There's one problem though. I've found that the control centre is minimalistic (to say the least) and, coming from a guy with Yast2, that's a bit of a problem. My particular problem here is that i'm trying to reformat an old HDD to an NTFS file extension, and i'm not exactly sure how. I'd prefer it if this is GUI driven, a, while i certainly am confident with a terminal, i don't like the idea of using it to reformat an HDD.

Now, not only do i want to reformat, i'd also like to partition it. i.e: 700GB NFTS and 500GB whatever extension Ubuntu uses.

Comment: Have you given Gparted a trial.. install it **[sudo apt-get install gparted]** and try it out

Comment: We do not add 'solved' to a title or edit the answer into the question on AU. Please make it an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Rexoanimation solved the problem and explained the solution in [an edit](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/521403/2):

> Disk utility is called: Disks - had to search for it.